# Deployment not running due to ImagePullBackOff reason

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, docker-image, kubernetes-secrets

I'm trying to create a deployment that is pulling a container image from a private registry.

My deployment.yaml file:

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: my-app
>   namespace: my-namespace
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: my-app
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: my-app
>     spec:
>       containers:
>         - name: my-app
>           image: my-repo/my-app:1.0
>       imagePullSecrets:
>         - name: regcred
> ```

I'm deploying with the following command: kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml -n my-namespace.

The deployment is not running due to the ImagePullBackOff.

I checked available resources to troubleshoot this issue and ruled out the following:

- my image and tag exist in the repo
- the secret works for other images

Pod description wasn't super helpful to me. I see the following:

> state:
> waiting:
> message: Back-off pulling image "my-repo/my-app:tag"
> reason: ImagePullBackOff

I don't understand why in the pod description, namespace is listed as 'default'. This is my only remaining straw that I'm grasping to.

> apiVersion: v1 kind: Pod metadata:   annotations:
> ..org/containerID: ...
> ..org/podIP: ...
> ..org/podIPs:    creationTimestamp: ""   generateName: ...   labels:
> app: my-app
> pod-template-hash: ...   name: ...   namespace: **default**

I would appreciate any suggestions how to troubleshoot this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original deployment.yaml did not contain namespace, so the pod was attempting to deploy in the default namespace. The secret was created in a different namespace. Once I added namespace to the manifest, the pod deployed successfully in the specified namespace.
My problem was that I was looking for pods in the default namespace and kept on seeing the originally failed deployment. Once I looked in the correct namespace `kubectl get pods -n my-namespace`, I saw that the pod is running and pulling the correct image.